# Can't see any files on my external hard drive

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

On my external hard drive, after I first start up my computer, it works fine and all the files work fine. But after my computer has been on for a while, the files in the external hard drive are still visible but not accessible.
The icons for all the files become generic icons and won't load the actual thumbnails of pics, videos, music, etc. After an even longer time of my computer being on, the files completely disappear.

I just recently (after seeing my files were all gone) tried unplugging my external hard drive while my computer was on and plugging it back in and now the files are all visible again and working properly. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening or how to fix it?

This was first brought to my attention when I was using my external hard drive to download torrent files and after completing downloads, the torrents wouldn't upload and the error message given on the torrent downloader was cyclic redundancy check. When I looked into this, it seemed like the problem was a bad sector on my external hard drive but after restarting my computer (which made all the files visible and working again), I don't think that's the case so now I have no idea what the problem is.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any hardware problem like loose USB / power cord?  Is the power saving mode setting made the drive disconnected?

Comment: Can I assume when you say you can't see any files, you can still access the external hard drive? There are many reasons for this to happen such as faulty hard-ware (bad hard drive)

Comment: Adam, [can you edit your question](http://superuser.com/posts/744942/edit) and add some spacing/paragraphs etc. It's really hard to read.

Comment: This sounds more like a "resources" issue, in my words that means some aspect of the memory but not defined or seen in ram usage. Like some program leaking (or driver but I dont think that applies here). Please tag it for the operating system, and it would be interesting to know what service pack, or if the updates have been done, because some things similar were patched up in updates.

Comment: @Ken As far as I can tell, there are no problems with USB or power cords and the power saving mode isn't making it disconnect.

Comment: @Dave Yes, the drive is still accessible and I can explore it but the folders are all empty.

Comment: @Psycogeek I am running Windows 7, service pack 1. It had been a long time since I had installed any updates. They had been downloaded but just waiting for me to restart my computer. I just recently restarted to let them finish installing, but that was after I already encountered this problem.

Comment: Just a quick update: I've had this external hard drive for about a year now and this is the first problem I've had with it and it just happened all of a sudden. As far as I can remember, I didn't make any changes to my system recently so I don't think that could be it.

Comment: Just note that you've got a "cyclic redundancy check error"... If you are sure it's not related to bad sector, what if you change the ext HDD write caching policy to disable write caching?  (Device manager > Disk drives > [HDD] > Properties > Policies > Optimize for quick removal) It may affect performance but sometimes make the data consistent.

Comment: At any rate, your going to need to have a backup of it. Once you get a backup you could run a chkdsk /F on it.  Then run some simple "smart" utility to see.

Comment: @Ken I just tried to disable write caching but when I checked, it was already on Quick removal by default. Would it change anything if I changed the removal policy to Better performance? Also, I'm not sure if this matters but I never unplug this external hard drive. It's been plugged in ever since I got it.

Comment: "Quick Removal" is the safer method, especially if you were having problems you would leave it there.

Comment: What's your settings in Control Panel > Power Options? Is the "Turn off hard disks" option set to "Never"?

Comment: @Psycogeek I can probably backup most of the important files I have on that external hard drive but I don't have enough room on my hard drive to backup everything. And it's kind of hard to do at the moment. I don't have a very large window of opportunity to transfer files before they become inaccessible. Also, if I'm not mistaken, if I use chkdsk and it finds bad sectors on the drive, doesn't it make those sectors, and any information on them, permanently unusable?

Comment: @Ken "Turn off hard disks" was set to 20 minutes. Should I change it to "Never"? I've only just recently had this problem with the external hard drive though and I've never changed this setting before.

Comment: @Adam No harm to give a try to set it "Never".  You can always change it back to 20 minutes if you have excluded this reason.

Comment: Generally chkdsk will fix everything fine, anything actually bad will be stored as best as it can, and everything goes fine. But if there was a problem, and something like a head goober or crash can expand, the more the head passes over it. so a backup first, then hope that chkdisk doesn't even see anything wrong.

Comment: @Adam Have you tried 'Check drive for file system errors'

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing the drive letter assigned to your external Hard drive from the disk management. I am sure it will work, in most of the cases it works.